# LCD capacitor issue fixing itself after some time

Tags: display, lcd, capacitor

I have a Viewsonic XG3240C 144hz monitor. Recently it started having problems when turned on after being off for some time (8-10 hours).

It shows distorted horizontal lines at the bottom of the screen, but after a couple of minutes the lines go away, and it works as it should. It only repeats after being off overnight. And it only happens at high refresh rates (>100hz).

Btw the problem is definitely in the monitor; cable & pc are alright, cause I've tried different configurations (another pc, another cable etc., also another dc adapter).

So I took it apart and checked for loose connections, everything is fine. At first I thought it was a temperature issue. The screen gets cold over night, and needs some time to warm up after that. So I put the monitor outside for couple of hours, and it was freezing after that, and turned it on, no problems (only 1-2 hours had passed).

So it means it's not a temperature issue but a "time" issue. So I thought, what electrical components are affected by time? Capacitors, right? They can hold their charge for a while after the unit is off, and if it sits for a while, one of the caps must be fully discharging, and then it has trouble when turned on again. Also the problem started happening only recently, and caps can degrade over time, so it must be a cap problem.

I've checked for bumps on caps (you know, problematic caps tend to make a bump at the top) but none of them have it, so I took my chances and replaced all the TTH cylindrical caps on the board. But the problem is still there. There are other SMD caps which are harder to replace, so I stopped there.

Now I'm wondering if I'm going the right way here. Do you think it would work if I also replace all the SMD caps? (I mean the big ones). There are also very tiny caps all over the place (also on the board of the panel) but I think they wouldn't hold charges for hours so they cannot be the problem, right?

The only thing that would be affected by a timespan of 10 hours and have a change in their "state" are the big capacitors, is that right? I know some basic electronics and soldering etc.

But I'm not totally sure if my reasoning makes sense here so I would like some opinions on that (also excuse me if I'm being all wrong here). I say thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm far from an electronics expert;) I can see your reasoning, however, I would expect the caps to be fully charged again within seconds of powering up. They're not really there to 'hold' charge but to smooth it. The fact that they do hold charge is really just a side effect of their actual task.